# gvim: any way to switch to text mouse cursor?

Tags: vim

Is there anyway to change the mouse cursor to the text one when it is over a buffer? Like this:

[image]

Comment: It does when you're in insert mode.

Comment: What does "over a buffer" mean?

Comment: @romainl I mean over the code, over the file text.

Comment: The cursor is always *on* a character in normal mode. What would be the point of having an I-beam cursor? Making it harder to use Vim?

Comment: @romainl I think the I-beam cursor is more accurate to start to select text, dont you think? I dont now what you mean with "Making it harder to use Vim?", sorry because my english..

Comment: Who is talking about selecting text? Your question is about the default appearance of the cursor, isn't it? Because the cursor is always on a character there's no point displaying it as a bar between characters. That makes absolutely no sense whatsoever.

Comment: Well, I see now that I completely missed the point of your question because I never use the mouse. You should break that habit, too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the option `mouseshape`. Get more information with:

```
:help 'mouseshape'
```

Try to adding `n=beam` to the setting:

```
:set mouseshape+=n:beam
```

Comment: @michail.kebe thanks! that works, but when I select a piece of text, the cursor transform again to the arrow till I click in another part.

Comment: I would like it to be always the text mouse cursor.

Comment: @tirengarfio Hmm, I don't know, but I think you will find a solution, if you read the help about 'mouseshape'. You could try to remove all other options and then just add the one you want.